# Don't show uninteresting files in Emacs completion window

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, find, dot-emacs

How do I prevent Emacs from showing me all the files I'm not interested in (such as ~ backup files, .pyc files, or .orig files) when I: C-x C-f *TAB* ?

It is working in one respect: if I know the file I want to open begins with *foo* and I type foo *TAB* then the mini-buffer correctly autocompletes all the way to foo.py. It correctly ignored foo~ and foo.pyc, because both ~ and .pyc are in [completion-ignored-extensions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/File-Name-Completion.html). It also correctly lets me open either ignored file if I really want to by typing in all the letters my self.

However, if I just hit *TAB* to to bring up the completion list buffer then that list includes files with extensions in *completion-ignored-extensions*, which makes it very difficult to find what I'm looking for.

Clearly the code to ignore uninteresting files is there and working. How do I get the completion list buffer to respect *completion-ignored-extensions*?

(by-the-by, can I make dired behave similarly?)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This piece of advice filters out files with extensions listed in `'completion-ignored-extensions`:

```
(defadvice completion--file-name-table (after 
                                        ignoring-backups-f-n-completion 
                                        activate)
  "Filter out results when they match `completion-ignored-extensions'."
  (let ((res ad-return-value))
(if (and (listp res)
     (stringp (car res))
     (cdr res))                 ; length > 1, don't ignore sole match
    (setq ad-return-value
              (completion-pcm--filename-try-filter res)))))
```

*Note:* This doesn't affect `dired`.

For the `dired` issue, add this to your .emacs

```
(eval-after-load "dired"
  '(require 'dired-x))

(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (dired-omit-mode 1)))
```

Read the [documentation for dired-x](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/dired-x/index.html#Top) to get an idea of what's available there.

Comment: Almost perfect! Any chance the advice can be modified to respect the variable completion-ignored-extensions?

Comment: Yup, now uses `completion-ignored-extensions`.

Answer (score 9):

I would recommend using [ido-mode](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/10/10/introduction-to-ido-mode/) to ignore files; it comes with Emacs by default and adds many other useful enhancements that you'll quickly learn to love. The [Ignorance is Bliss section from this Mastering Emacs blog post](http://www.masteringemacs.org/articles/2010/10/10/introduction-to-ido-mode/) covers how to ignore files, directories, and buffers:

- `ido-ignore-buffers`  Takes a list of buffers to ignore in <kbd>C-x b</kbd>
- `ido-ignore-directories`  Takes a list of directories to ignore in <kbd>C-x d</kbd> and <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>
- `ido-ignore-files`    Takes a list of files to ignore in <kbd>C-x C-f</kbd>

Comment: As its Ignorance is Bliss section also says: I don’t ignore anything in Ido beyond the defaults, as I prefer to use the more general `completion-ignored-extensions` as it works with and without Ido.

Comment: @SimonShine I have found that `completion-ignored-extensions` works for most things, but for some reason it does not work for `ido-dired` (which is bound to `C-x d` when Ido mode is on). The only way to have an effect on `ido-dired` seems to be by setting `ido-ignore-directories`. At least, that is what I see as of Emacs 25.3.

Answer (score 3):

[***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) does what you expect by default. It always respects `completion-ignored-extensions` for file-name completion, including for buffer `*Completions*`.  And you can toggle this ignoring on/off at anytime, by hitting <kbd>C-.</kbd> in the minibuffer.

In addition, if you use library [`completion-ignored-build.el`](http://user42.tuxfamily.org/completion-ignored-build/index.html) by Kevin Ryde, then **Icicles** automatically takes advantage of that library's dynamic adjustment of ignored file extensions.  (Just load `completion-ignored-build.el` -- do not enable its minor mode or advice.)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of an answer for completion, I'm afraid. I think this is by design - when you know the name you're looking for, you probably don't want e.g. the backup file. But when you don't know, it's probably better to have a list of all of the files.

However, for dired, you can load the 'dired-x' package on startup (in your .emacs), and this provides dired-omit-mode:

```
(load "dired-x")
```

You can use 'M-x customize-variable<RET>dired-omit-files'  to set the actual patterns to ignore. Then when you are in dired mode you can use M-O (the letter, not the number) to toggle 'omission' on and off.

Comment: Nice. I like the way dired says "Omitted 26 lines." (or whatever) hen you open a directory. I think the same could happen for the file completion list, which would mitigate your concern about hiding files which might sometimes be needed. Pressing TAB again could show all files (like M-o).